# How to display a pdf file in web browser in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a pdf file named 102.pdf in my App_Data folder.
I want to view this in my web browser like chrome.Here is my code. But I can not display it.

```
<iframe src="102.pdf" width="400" height="400"></iframe>
```

I am using VS11

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't you need to specify the App_Data folder?  src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/App_Data/102.pdf")%>"

Comment: As far as I know you will have to have an application installed that can actually do something with the pdf. Like Adobe Acrobat Reader or some sort of web browser extension. The web browser will only (maybe) display the pdf if the file association is supported on the operating system.

Comment: I have Adobe reader installed. I am wondering this code works fine in php. But its not working on MVC3 @Tomas

Comment: @ChrisGessler I am usign razor engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`

```
<iframe src="@Url.Content("~/Content/pdfs/102.pdf")" width="1000" height="500"></iframe>
```

`

Its the solution for how to view a pdf file in asp.net MVC3 with razor engine.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this : http://forums.asp.net/t/1506499.aspx/1?Dynamic+pdf+generation+using+iTextSharp

And is it a requirement to render pdf? what you can do is produce a markup of the same pdf file in browser and make it available for download in pdf using lib like itext http://itextpdf.com/.

Comment: Think that he just wants to have an existing pdf appear in an iframe

Comment: Ok I do not want to generate pdf :) But I have already have a pdf and I want to display it on my webpage.

Comment: `<embed src="102.pdf #toolbar=1&navpanes=0&scrollbar=1" width="1000" height="1000">` This portion of code workes fine in php except asp.net MVC3 razor engine